# Label text changing with If condition on Kivy 2.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, kivy, kivy-language

I am new here. I have a question.
I want to change the label text with if condition in `kv.` file, it must be changed the text according to button pressed. But I receive an error.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv ='''
BoxLayout:
    Label:
        id:counter_text
        text:'0'
    Label:
        text: 'Number increases' if myswitch.on_press else 'number added 1'
    Button:
        id:myswitch
        text:'COUNTER'
        on_press:app.increment()
        
    Button:
        text:'RESET'
        on_press:app.reset()
'''

class CounterApp(App):
    counter = 0
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def increment(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print(self.counter)
        self.root.ids.counter_text.text= str(self.counter)

    def reset(self):
        self.counter = 0
        print(self.counter)
        self.root.ids.counter_text.text = str(self.counter)

CounterApp().run()
```

error output is here.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
call_fn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'
  File "C:\...\counttest.py", line 40, in <module>
    CounterApp().run()
```

Does anybody have any idea for the solution? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that will help you:

```
Label:
    text: "Number increases" if myswitch.state =="down" else "number added 1"
```

Comment: thanks @gorzk for your answer. Now if I click the button, changes the text and swipe the finger, label text gets back to old state. Is there any way to toggle the button?

Comment: In your case, you can simply change `Button:` to `ToggleButton:` in your `kv` string